# Java7 / Path / File / get a unique ID like an Inode of a file

Tags: java, java-7

How do I get a unique ID from a `Path` or `File` instance which must have an Inode or another unique ID in a "non Linux/Unix" filesystem? Can't find anything in the API, do I have to use JNI?

Edit: I have two reasons:

- I want to have a unique mapping from a file in the filesystem to a tree-based representation in a database system.
- I want to detect renames of a file, which results in a deletion event and a new insertion event when watching a `Path` via `WatchService` (at least for Linux/Unix filesystems). Therefore I can't use a `Path` to detect such renames.

BTW: At first I thought `WatchService` would trigger an `java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY` event in case of renames, but I suppose that's Filesystem dependent and/or only happens if the file content itself changes.

So I suppose I would really have to use a JNI-binding to detect renames and maybe moves?

Edit: I think I've finally found how to get a unique file representation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#fileKey()

Comment: Can't the full path to the file be used? That ought to be unique. Or maybe turn the path's characters into a hex representation...

Comment: What do you want to do with this? Do you just want uniqueness to be guaranteed? Or do you need the actual real inode number from the OS? If the latter, why?

Comment: `Files.getFileStore(file.toPath).getAttribute("unix:inod")`.

Comment: @KaiSellgren unix:inod didn't work for me. Instead this helped: Files.getAttribute(path, "unix:ino")

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a unique id, you can hash the file path (using sha1) and it will give you an *unique text id*.

If you want the real id associated with the file, you'll need to use JNI and have a custom library for each OS.

Comment: Hashes are (by definition) not unique, so its not a good idea to use them as identifiers.

Comment: Well, at least git uses a strong hash algorithm with a decent hash length, so the chances for collisions are not that big. But for example one should never use the result of hashCode() as an id. 32bit are too short for that, and most implementations of that method use very weak "algorithms".

Comment: No!  This is not true for many reasons. Two textually different paths can be associated with the same file--consider the case of a path that includes a symlink, and one that contains a hardlink.

Answer (score 0):

A UNC path would be a unique key: "/ / SERVER / PATH / PATH / FILENAME",
with an additional File.getCanonicalPath(). At least under Windows as opposed to drive letters.